# Finding the sum of a path in a tree

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a function that tests whether or not there is a path that sums up to my value `sum1`. I am not sure why my function is wrong but I assume from the output that it is running too many times. My tree seems to be working properly the first few times it runs recursively but as it gets deeper and deeper into the recursion, it seems to do too much

input:

`hasPathSum(r,20)`

output:

```
has Path sum?
12
7
5
False
```

my function:

```
def hasPathSum(root,sum1):
    # Given a tree and a sum, return true if there is a path from the root
    # down to a leaf, such that adding up all the values along the path
    # equals the given sum
    # Strategy: Subtract the node value from the sum when recurring down,
    # and check to see if the sum is 0 when you run out of tree
    if not root:   # negative values? make sum == 0?
        return False
    else:
        sum1 = sum1 - root.value
        if sum1 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            if root.left is not None:
                print sum1
                return hasPathSum(root.left, sum1)
            if root.right is not None:
                print sum1
                return hasPathSum(root.right, sum1)
        return False
```

my tree:

```
r = Node(8)

#left

a = Node(5)
b = Node(2)
c = Node(1)
d = Node(3)
e = Node(7)

#right


f = Node(14)
g = Node(11)
h = Node(10)
i = Node(15)
j = Node(19)
k = Node(20)
l = Node(21)

BST_Insert(r, a)
BST_Insert(r, b)
BST_Insert(r, c)
BST_Insert(r, d)
BST_Insert(r, e)
BST_Insert(r, f)
BST_Insert(r, g)
BST_Insert(r, h)
BST_Insert(r, i)
BST_Insert(r, j)
BST_Insert(r, k)
BST_Insert(r, l)
```

Comment: When you recurse into your left/right paths, you are throwing away the return value

Comment: @fileoffset i understand what you are saying. I see my flaw

Comment: @fileoffset i added return value to my recursive functions but i still get the same output =/

Comment: A minor point: `if root is None:` will fail when `root` is any kind of falsey value, because `[] is None` is `False`. `is` checks for _identity_ not equality. Your statement is saying "if root is the same thing as the object None", when you probably want "if root is a false value", like say an empty string, a different object. You should change the condition to `if not root:`; or make it more specific as `if not hasattr(root, 'left') or hasattr(root, 'right'):`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i understand! thank you for pointing this out to me! much appreciated!

Comment: Your edit won't work, because if a node has both a left and right node, it will only evaluate the left and return that value. What you should have is something like: `return hasPathSum(root.left, sum1) or hasPathSum(root.right, sum1)`

Comment: @fileoffset sorry Im still new to python and Im a bit confused. I dont understand why my code doesn't print out 3 after the 5. For your suggestion, i think if the two recursive functions are processed and I get True or False with an OR logic only the True will appear.

Comment: @fileoffset your piece of code works and for the most part i think i understand it but i feel bad because I sorta wanted to solve this problem my way or similar to my method. that way I would learn the most haha

Comment: @fileoffset I think i understand what you meant at first now actually. My logic doesn't work because it constantly goes through the tree left. It only stops if `sum1==0` or if I reach an empty node. This causes `sum1` to be continuously altered and that altered value is later passed to `hasPathSum(root.right,sum1)` which will also only stop when `sum1==0` or it reaches a empty node. Is what I am saying correct?

Comment: Kind of. The problem is that you say 'if there is a left node, follow it and whatever value you get back, return it immediately'. Do you see that if a left node is set, then you will always check the left node, but no matter if the left node is right or wrong, you will always return the value of that search. You will never actually even _try_ the right node, except in cases where there is _no_ left node defined. That's the problem. My code checks both paths (left and right) and returns true if either is true, else false.